# Compiz Config animations does not work (ubuntu mate)

Tags: compiz, ubuntu-mate

i downloaded compizconfig settings manager and even though i'm enabling some animations they do not work, for example i enabled the wobbly windows animation and it does not work.

I'm running ubuntu mate 18.04 on a virtual machine on my lenovo yoga 710 latop.
thanks for the help.